# Encrypt existing TM-backup when the source computer is missing?

Tags: backup, time-machine, encryption

I have a bunch of Time Machine archives for old computers I no longer have. I want to encrypt these archives. Can that be done using a different computer than the one that was backed up?

I have looked that the *tmutil* man-page and found a couple of interesting options there:

**inheritbackup** - seems to make it possible to use the TM-destination for machine A for machine B. However, there is a caveat in the instructions:

*Inheriting is typically only one step in the process of configuring a backup for use by a machine. You may also need to use **setdestination**, **associatedisk**, or both, depending on the situation.*

Since this is backup data I don't want to lose or corrupt I am a bit hesitant to experiment (I have copies but if I perform a couple of operations and everything looks fine and I therefore delete my copies just to, a year from now, realise that I broke something I won't be too happy...). Would be nice with a HOWTO or step-by-step guide, if possible.

Comment: You may want to go with a method that is not dependent on *any particular* Mac. EG encrypt it with a password that does not have to be associated with a particular Mac, like (I believe) **inheritbackup** does.

Comment: Please don't double post the same question - instead, [edit the original](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/398753/edit).